# Group Java Development

Tags: java, eclipse, synchronization, parallel-processing

Maybe it's a strange question but...

A friend of mine and I used to code together on small projects. Everyone has their own expertise in coding things.

This works quite well when coding in C on a remote location (over ssh on the same server).

My Question: Is there a possibility of developing java with eclipse with 2 or more people. Same time, same project, same files.

I know I can use SVN and make commit and update very often.

But: Is there a way to program in parallel on eclipse projects in "realtime" ?

Thanks,

Andre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code is code, the fact that your code will be executed by a JVM or something else won't change the way you code.

For the part of realtime coding, it's not really a good idea, when you work on some part of your project, if you break the compilation or anything else you don't really want to mess the code of your coworkers/friends.

---

On the other hand there are ways to share code and live code with other persons on the same file (for example for pair programming).

In Eclipse the plugin is named [DocShare](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DocShare_Plugin). For Netbeans the [Collaboration Module](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/quickstart-collaboration.html) will do the trick. For IntelliJ, [IDETalk](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ide_talk.html) won't really allow realtime sharing but will really help.

---

**Resources :**

- [eclipse - DocShare](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DocShare_Plugin)

Comment: Ok than ... is there an option to automatically commit and update once every 2 min or so (if the build suceeds)?

Comment: @Bigbohne, Thats not good as Colin said, with that you can mess your coworker's code. the best way is to checkout and lock the class or object you are working on, and release it when you finish with it, so if your partner were working on the same object, they won't be able to commit their code without manually merging it...

Comment: I think that the point of collaborative plugins is more to allow remote developers to see changes in real time than to make (concurrent) changes in the same time. That's not how I would use them at least.

Comment: I totally agree, I was saying that because of the "old method" given above, "the project shared over SSH on a server" which is a bad practice.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok, got it now. And fully agree.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a possibility of developing java with eclipse with 2 or more people. Same time, same project, same files.

Eclipse has two plugins called [DocShare](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DocShare_Plugin) and [Saros](http://www.saros-project.org/) (available via the [marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/saros-distributed-collaborative-editing-and-pair-programming)) that allow real-time collaborative editing of documents (DocShare) or projects (Saros).

> Saros is an Eclipse plugin for collaborative text editing and
>   distributed pair programming, i.e. it allows two or more developers to
>   work together in real-time on the same files. It is similar to Gobby,
>   SubEthaEdit or Google Docs but focuses on programming in Eclipse.

Have a look at the [Demo Video](http://www.saros-project.org/w/SE/DPPDemoVideo) from Saros.